# d3 js axis does not match the actual data

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn d3, and got in some trouble with matching the data to the axis.

checkout this snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

        body {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            margin: 30px;
        }

        path.line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #666;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }


        .axis {
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }


        .x.axis path {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
        }

        .y.axis line, .y.axis path {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
        }



    </style>
    <svg class="chart"></svg>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
                width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        //The data for our line
        var lineData = [{"x": 1, "y": 5}, {"x": 20, "y": 20},
            {"x": 40, "y": 10}, {"x": 60, "y": 40},
            {"x": 80, "y": 5}, {"x": 100, "y": 60}];

        var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([height,0]),
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

        x.domain([0,100]);
        y.domain([0,100]);

        //This is the accessor function we talked about above
        var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                })
                .interpolate("monotone");

        //The SVG Container
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        //The line SVG Path we draw
        var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("class","path");


        // Add the x-axis.
        svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        // Add the y-axis.
        svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);


    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The axis numbers looks ok, but the points does not match.

what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up your scales `x` and `y` and assigned them to your axes, but you missed to specifiy them in your accessor functions. Since your data point should scale the same way that the axes do you need to use them like so:

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.y);
        })
        .interpolate("monotone");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

        body {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            margin: 30px;
        }

        path.line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #666;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }


        .axis {
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }


        .x.axis path {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
        }

        .y.axis line, .y.axis path {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
        }



    </style>
    <svg class="chart"></svg>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
                width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        //The data for our line
        var lineData = [{"x": 1, "y": 5}, {"x": 20, "y": 20},
            {"x": 40, "y": 10}, {"x": 60, "y": 40},
            {"x": 80, "y": 5}, {"x": 100, "y": 60}];

        var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([height,0]),
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

        x.domain([0,100]);
        y.domain([0,100]);

        //This is the accessor function we talked about above
        var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return x(d.x);
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return y(d.y);
                })
                .interpolate("monotone");

        //The SVG Container
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        //The line SVG Path we draw
        var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("class","path");


        // Add the x-axis.
        svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        // Add the y-axis.
        svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);


    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```